# ReactNative: Exception in native GuidedStepSupportFragment call (Android LeanBack)

Tags: android, react-native, android-native-library

When I try to render native guided step fragment in react native, I am getting the below error.

ReactNative: Exception in native call
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.hello:layout/lb_guidedstep_fragment: For input string: "?2130903438"
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "?2130903438"

public class MyGuidedStepFragment extends GuidedStepSupportFragment {

```
private static final long ACTION_CONTINUE = 1000;
private static final long ACTION_CANCEL = 2000;

public MyGuidedStepFragment() {}

@NonNull
@Override
public GuidanceStylist.Guidance onCreateGuidance(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String title = "Login";
    String breadcrumb = "Welcome to App";
    String description = "Complete the step to get Signed In";
    Drawable icon = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_lock);
    return new GuidanceStylist.Guidance(title, description, breadcrumb, icon);
}

@Override
public void onCreateActions(@NonNull List<GuidedAction> actions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateActions(actions, savedInstanceState);
    actions.add(new GuidedAction.Builder()
            .id(ACTION_CONTINUE)
            .title("Continue")
            .description("Click to continue login")
            .hasNext(false)
            .build());

    actions.add(new GuidedAction.Builder()
            .id(ACTION_CANCEL)
            .title("Cancel")
            .description("Click to cancel login")
            .hasNext(false)
            .build());
}

@Override
public void onGuidedActionClicked(GuidedAction action) {
    super.onGuidedActionClicked(action);
    long actionId = action.getId();
    if (actionId == ACTION_CONTINUE) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ACTION CONTINUE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (actionId == ACTION_CANCEL) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ACTION CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "NO MATCHING ACTION FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

View manager:

public class MyGuidedStepManager extends ViewGroupManager {

```
private static final String REACT_CLASS = "MyGuidedStepManager";
public final int COMMAND_CREATE = 1;
private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

public MyGuidedStepManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected MyGuidedStepLayout createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    MyGuidedStepFragment myGuidedStepFragment = new MyGuidedStepFragment();
    MyGuidedStepLayout myGuidedStepLayout = new MyGuidedStepLayout(reactContext, myGuidedStepFragment);
    addView(myGuidedStepLayout, myGuidedStepFragment.getView(), 0);
    return myGuidedStepLayout;
}
```

React native side:

import React from 'react';
import { MyGuidedStep } from '@hello/abc';

const MyGuidedStepView = () => {
return (

)
};

export default MyGuidedStepView;

Answer (score 0):

This may be late for this question, but I have the exact problem and adding `Theme_Leanback_GuidedStep` to the `GuidedStepSupportFragment` solved the problem!

```
override fun onProvideTheme(): Int {
    return androidx.leanback.R.style.Theme_Leanback_GuidedStep
}
```

Hope this is helpful for someone else!